# Find the eigenvalues of block matrix $C$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Find the eigenvalues of $$C = \begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{c|c} 0 & A\\ \hline A^T & 0\end{array}\end{bmatrix}$$ where $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
> 0&0&0&1&1&1&1\\0& 1& 1& 0& 1& 0& 1\\0 &1 &1 &1 &0 &1 &0\\1& 0& 1& 0& 0& 1& 1\\1 &0 &1& 1& 1& 0& 0\\1 &1 &0& 0& 1& 1& 0\\1 &1& 0& 1& 0& 0 &1
> \end{bmatrix}$$

The characteristic polynomial of $C$ is $$\det(xI-C)=x^2-A^2$$

Will the eigenvalues of $A$ be related to those of $C$ in some way?

I am unable to proceed here.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\det(xI-C)=\det(x^2I-AA^T)$, the eigenvalues of $C$ are the singular values of $A$ and their negatives.

Now, note that $AA^T=2I+2ee^T$, where $e$ denotes the all-one vector. Hence the set of eigenvalues of $AA^T$ consists of a simple eigenvalue $2+2\times7=16$ and the eigenvalue $2$ of multiplicity $6$. It follows that the singular values of $A$ are $4$ and six copies of $\sqrt{2}$.

Hence the eigenvalues of $C$ are $+4,-4$, six copies of $\sqrt{2}$ and six copies of $-\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Could you explain $AA^T=2I+2ee^T$? Is it a specific property of the given matrix?

Comment: @user Just multiply $A$ by $A^T$ directly.

Comment: Two questions :1.How do you get that eigen values of $C$  are singular values of $A$ and their negatives from the equation $\det (x^2I-AA^T)=0$

Comment: Another one: 2:If an eigen value of $AA^T$ is $a$ how do you get that $\sqrt a$ is an eigen value of $A$

Comment: @New_User If $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $AA^T$, the characteristic polynomial of $AA^T$ is $p(t)=\det(tI-AA^T)=(t-\lambda_1)\cdots(t-\lambda_n)$. So, the characteristic polynomial of $C$ is $f(x)=\det(xI-C)=\det(x^2I-AA^T)=p(x^2)=(x^2-\lambda_1)\cdots(x^2-\lambda_n)$. Now the eigenvalues of $C$ are the roots of this characteristic polynomial. So, they are those $\pm\sqrt{\lambda_i}$s. But the square roots the $\lambda_i$s, by definition, are the singular values of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Something you have written is wrong but can be corrected. We have$$xI-C=\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{c|c}
xI & -A \\
\hline
-A^T & xI
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}$$therefore$$|xI-C|=|x^2I-A^TA|$$therefore $$x=\pm|\lambda|$$where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ therefore **the eigenvalues of $C$ are the $\pm$ singular values of $A$**

Comment: Yes thank you!.

Comment: I don't get how $|x^2I-A^TA|\implies x=\pm |\lambda|$

Comment: Can you explain please

Comment: You can refer to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SingularValue.html for further information